# WiX - Elevating (or reducing) privileges at install time

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vdproj

I am working on a project that has been using 2 VD projects to distribute admin and user versions of installations, and now I need to switch to WiX. It was a bit painful experience with lack of documentation and all, but I managed to make something of it.

However, there is still one problem: I want to make only one .msi which will allow user to choose whether he wants to install as admin or as user. If he chose user, I don't want to ask him for elevation (as he doesn't need it), also if he chose admin, I don't want the installation to crash but to ask for privileges.

My current solution crashes in admin mode if I set `InstallPrivileges` to `limited` because the user doesn't have the permission to install, and it prompts for elevation in user mode if I set it to `elevated`.

My opinion is that there is **no way** to fix this because of compatibility with MSI, but perhaps there is some way to change privileges from elevated to limited in install time that I'm missing.

In conclusion, I want to know these things:

- Is it possible to change privileges at install time
- If there is no way to do so, what is the best workaround for this problem (exporting 2 .msi files or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to build two separate installers and then launch them via a custom WiX bootstrapper (aka Burn). The bootstrapper would be in charge of displaying the UI and launching the appropriate .msi.

Or you could separate the "admin" features into a separate .msi and then use a custom bootstrapper to install both .msis if the user selects an admin install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Do you maybe happen to know if there is a way to somehow rerun the Votive command line (compiling and linking) after the original build run, only with changed `Product.wxs` file?

Comment: Not sure. What I would do is create two different configurations for your project/solution. In project properties > build, define a preprocessor variable for only one of those configurations. Then Product.wxs can include/exclude items based on the setting of the preprocessor varible.